# What is the best way to transport a large bike pack and two suitcases from Heathrow to Pinner?

Tags: uk, luggage, airport-transfer, london, lhr

My husband and I are traveling from Australia to London at the end of July. We will have the normal luggage plus a large bike pack. Can anyone give any suggestions as to the best way to transport our luggage to Pinner. Will taxi's be able to take a bike pack and 2 suit cases or is there another way of going? Any ideas of taxi costings?

Comment: Is a bike pack a bag containing a bike? Or it is a bag to be used strapped to a bike?

Comment: Taxi can, but book a taxi before arriving according to your requirements. While booking you can get options of different taxi types. Don't take one of the black cabs from outside. The traffic is heavy on your route and it will cost you dearly if you take one from outside the airport because of the slow moving traffic.

Comment: Thank you for the feed back. To JoErNan0.. It is a box measuring 1400x800x300 containing a bike.

Comment: To DumbCoder thank you for the taxi advise. Do you have a number of a taxi company you would suggest booking through. When you say don't take one from outside because of the slow moving traffic,  where do I meet up with the taxi I have booked? Does that make sense?

Comment: https://tfl.gov.uk/forms/12389.aspx. Check here for booking a minicab. Many have vehicles where your box can fit easily, so they may help you out. `I meet up with the taxi I have booked` I meant a black cab, not a booked mini cab. Or try to book a vehicle using Hertz or Avis. If you do want to book a black cab, this is https://tfl.gov.uk/modes/taxis-and-minicabs/book-a-taxi

Comment: Best how? Price? Speed? Not having to carry the luggage?

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to assume the bike is not a folding bike, otherwise you would have specified it as such.  Given that, you can't catch London buses or the Underground from Heathrow as [the former does not take non-folding bikes](http://www.heathrow-airport-guide.co.uk/london.html) and [the latter not from that station](https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/bicycle-tube-map.pdf).  Here are your options:

- To my mind the *best* option would be to find or make a friend in the UK with a decent size car.  They can pick you up from Heathrow and drop you off with little to no stress.
- Renting a car if you've got other plans beyond Pinner or intend to rent a car anyway is worth bringing forward - less cost than the non-self-powered options and less time required as well.
- [Taxis](http://www.ctc.org.uk/campaigning/views-and-briefings/taxis-and-private-hire-vehicles) will allegedly generally take bikes but I would suggest booking one and specifying the nature of your luggage to confirm that it will get taken to avoid disappointment.  Most convenient of the remainder, but also the most expensive.
- Public transport - [Heathrow Express will take bicycles outside of peak hours](https://www.heathrowexpress.com/conditions-of-carriage) (7:30 to 10:00 and 16:30 to 19:00), which gets you to Paddington Station.  Once there [you can get from Paddington to Baker Street and then on to Pinner](https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/bicycle-tube-map.pdf) while bringing the bike, outside of the 7:30 to 9:30 and 16:00 to 19:00 peak hours.  This is probably a compromise option.  You may need to buy a separate ticket for the bike box.
- [Ride the bike from Heathrow](http://www.heathrow.com/transport-and-directions/cycling) to Pinner.  Person #2 takes the luggage.  Probably the cheapest of the options.  Potentially the least convenient, especially if neither of you are familiar with London.

I didn't bother checking private buses because IMO the train transport would trump it, given the shorter changes required ([National Express](http://www.nationalexpress.com/airports/heathrow-airport.aspx), for example, drops you off near Victoria Station instead of near Baker Street).

Comment: Would uber be a viable substitute in lieu of a British friend? (I'm not sure if it or Lyft are active there)

Comment: Do you mean generally or in this specific scenario?  I don't know how inviting your Uber driver down to the pub to watch the game will go down, that's all...  At least with regards to the bikes, private taxis are often less spacious (in the traditional sense) so may have more issues fitting the bikes in.

Comment: Heh, I meant in this scenario, although I suspect if you want to leave the 'meter' running, he wouldn't mind :)

Comment: A large minicab will also do. Just call and book a van-type car specifying that you need to transport large luggage.

Comment: @JoErNanO That's what triggered my initial thought of answering this question but I couldn't find a number/website that gave that option... probably due to failure of searching rather than their non-existence though.